# jMeter - performance degrading with higher loop count

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I need a little help on how to debug the matter. My current jMeter scenario seems to run fine as long as I keep the loop count at 1, when I add more loops the performance starts to degrade a lot.

I have a thread group with 225 threads, 110s ramp up, loop count 1 - my total response time is ca. 8-9secs. I run this several times to confirm, each run shows similar response times. 
Now, I did the same test , just changed the loop count to 3, all other parameters unchanged, and the performance went south, total response time is ca. 30-40s.

I was under the impression that 3x 1 loop runs would be, more or less, equivalent to 1x 3 loops run. It seems that is not the matter. Anyone could explain to me why is that? 
Or, if this should be equivalent, any idea where to search for the culprit of degrading performance?

Answer (score 0):

What you're saying is that the response times degrade if you increase the throughput (as in requests per second).

Based on 225 threads making a single request with a rampup of 110 seconds your throughput is going to be in the region of 2 requests every second. Increasing the loop count to 3 is going to up that by around a factor of 3 to 6 requests a second (assuming no timers). Except of course if the response times are increasing then you will not reach this level of throughput which is you problem.

Given that this request is already taking 8-9 seconds, which is not especially fast, it could be assumed that there is some heavy thinking going on behind the scenes and that you have simply hit a bottleneck, somewhere...

Try using less threads and a longer rampup and then monitor the response times and the throughput rate. At some point, as the load increases, you will see response times start to degrade and then at this point you need to roll up your sleeves and have a look at what is happening in your AUT.

Note. 3 x 1 loop is not the same as 1 x 3 loops. The delay between iterations will cause one thread with multiple iterations to have a different throughput vs. more threads with one iteration where the throughput is decided by the rampup, not the delay. That said, this is not what you describe in your question - you mention that the number of threads is consistent.

Comment: The whole thread group takes ca. 15mins to execute as the scenario is not short and there are some timers involved, so basically 225 threads are reached after 110secs and kept at this level for more than 10 mins.

I believed that with both loop counts the scenario is pretty much the same, jMeter gets to 225 threads and stays there for the duration of the test. The only difference is that with 1 loop it stays there shorter than with 3 loops. Is that not the case?

The 8-9secs is for the whole thread. There is no visible stress on the back end servers.

Comment: Is it the second and third requests that are slower or all of them? Perhaps there is something different with subsequent requests in the same thread group, maybe you need a Cookie Manager or something like that. You can also verify the throughput using an Aggregate Results listener.

Comment: Not sure tbh, I have all results written into a file and then work with the result file. I see only the overall time increase. The request subset for the whole thread should be the same, there are some variables read from file, but there are 225 of them in the file, so each loop should be the same. I use cookie and cache managers, both cleared each iteration. Throughput is similar in both cases 1,9/sec with 1 loop, 1,7/sec with 3 loops. Response times for the whole thread are 7secs and 37secs respectively.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer from Oliver: try to use custom listener like [Active Threads Over Time Listener](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime) - to monitor your load-scenario.
You can also retry both your scenarios described above, with this listener - sure, you'll see the difference in graphs.

Comment: Yup, there is a difference. According to the ATOT graph the 1x scenario peaks at 200 concurrent threads ( and even that only for a moment ) and the 3x one at 225 ( for a longer period of time ). This is strange as during the test the 225 thread count seems to last for a longer period for both scenarios ( as seen in the upper right corner of jmeter, not on any listeners ).